# SQL Join Table Naming Convention

Tags: sql, sql-server, naming-conventions

I have 2 tables: Users and Roles, and I have a table that joins these together. The only thing in the join table is Ids that link the 2 tables.

What should I call this table? I've never really seen a good naming convention for this.

Conventions I've seen before:

- UsersToRolesJoin
- UsersToRolesLink
- UsersToRolesMembership
- UsersRoles

Ex:

```
Users:  
Id  
Name

Roles:  
Id  
Name  

TableThatJoinsTheTwo:  
Id  
UserId  
RoleId
```

Comment: Nice question - interested to see what the answers are.  Of course, the tables should be called User and Role (not pluralised), but that's a whole nother argument :)

Comment: I generally pluralize table names just because it makes more sense visibly.  I don't have a table of user, I have a table of users.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It seems like the mapping table is storing all the roles that each user is a member of.  If this is correct I would call the table `UserRoles`.

This correctly (IMO) pluralizes the intent of the table rather than `UsersRoles` which just sounds odd.

Comment: The table equally describes all roles that a user has as it does all users that a role has. So UsersRoles makes sense.

Answer (score 33):

I'd call the users table `User`, the roles table `Role` and the join table `UserRoles`.

By the way, the pk `Id` is not really necessary in a join table. Better make the `UserId` and `RoleId` together the pk or just uk (unique key) so that you can ensure unique `User`-`Role` relationships.

Comment: No Primary Key?  Why?  I though best practice was to always have PK?

Comment: @Sonny: Because you're usually never interested in a single row of a join table. It only unnecessarily costs one extra index.

Comment: `(User, Role)` make a nice composite `PK` for this table. There is no need in creating a surrogate.

Comment: @Balus Even if it's a high-traffic table where the links are changing thousands of times a day?  In our app we have many of our links as objects that hold the PK so they can be deleted (or in some rare cases updated).  I'm not disagreeing with you, it's just that we never thought of NOT having a PK.  :P

Comment: `@BalusC`: a join table does need a `PK`, but not a *surrogate* `PK`. What it needs is a composite `PK` made out of the `FKs` it links.

Comment: @Sonny If you want a primary key, you could simply make a multi-column primary key that spans UserId and RoleId (assuming that one user can't be added to the same role twice :)

Comment: We're talking about a PK in a **JOIN TABLE**. A join table doesn't need a PK. It doesn't represent a real world entity. It just links entities together. You already have keys in flavor of the UserId and RoleId.

Comment: @Quassnoi and Scott: exactly that is what I was trying to tell.

Comment: @BalusC: I would call the relation table 'UserRole' without s given that you suggest the original table names in singular form - for consistency.

Comment: @van: Depends. In our case the `s` at end of table name indicates a join table.

Answer (score 25):

I would suggest simply *UsersRoles*, as that is what it holds.

Comment: Also remove the 'Id' column unless really required for some reason; Assuming that the lookups are more often done from User side, create a CLUSTERED PK on (UserId, RoleId) and another index on (RoleId, UserId) or just RoleId but including UserId.

Answer (score 12):

- Table names should always be singular, that way later you don't have to be like "is it `User` or `Users`? What about things that end in an S? etc" (I would change this now if you just started the project)
- The common convention would be: `User`, `Role`, and the xref table: `UserRole`.
- The most important table, or the one that existed before goes first. This is specially true if the 'role' table has no real use outside user permission stuff. so `UserRole` makes much more sense than `RoleUser`.
- I've seen things like `User_X_Role` or `UserXRole` as well, if you like the extra verbosity

Comment: This is how my ORM works (and many others): collections returned are pluralized names of the entity.

Answer (score 10):

The database represents am enterprise, right? So what do the people in that enterprise call the relationship?

Here are some I do know:

- `employee` reports to `line manager` == org chart
- `student` takes `course` == enrolment
- `woman` marries `man` == marriages

When in doubt, ask a domain expert within the enterprise.

Comment: This is a very good point, and I think it should be used more.  For example, 'Enrollment' is crystal clear as to what it is over Student_Course_Link.

Answer (score 7):

I'd call the link table this:

```
Remove_The_Surrogate_Primary_Key_From_The_Link_Table_Unless_You_Can_Prove_That_You_Really_Need_One
```

Comment: +1 nice one, although there's usually a limit on table name length =)

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah... In my case, I actually don't need it and will be using a composite primary key.

Comment: `@Josh Close`: Just name your table `UserRole` then :)

Comment: ...but remove the `_Link` part.

Comment: While funny and accurate, this doesn't really answer the original question. I much prefer BalusC's answer. And yes, I know this is an old question.

Comment: @Akrikos: is that extra s that important?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I don't really care about the 's' as long as whatever you're doing you do consistently. Although, having an 's' after each of the concatenated names sounds silly to me.

Comment: In Oracle, I had to name my link tables `Remove_The_Surrogate_Primary01`, `Remove_The_Surrogate_Primary02`, etc. :(

Answer (score 6):

We have the same structure and call the link table UserRoles.

Comment: Same here.  I prefer plural names for tables (since the users table will typically hold a set of users, not a single user).  But when you then link a user to the roles they are in, UserRoles makes sense.

Comment: Another good argument might be that many to many might need the Links in the name such that we refer to UserRoleLinks. Might work, but it is up to you X-)

Answer (score 4):

This is the convention at my workplace:

```
UsersXRoles
```

Comment: I like this and going to use this. Instead of Roles, we have two table named `user` and `user_group`, and calling the link table `user_user_group` kinds of get confusing. `user_x_user_group` looks good!

Answer (score 3):

I've been thinking carefully about this, and I would link the table `User` and the table `Role` with the table `UsersRoles`.  I think its nice, because it indicates that the many-to-many relationship could be considered as linking many roles to one user, or indeed many users to one role (so both being plural makes sense).  It can also be read as "Users' roles", indicating that the normal way of thinking about the relationship is the "roles that a user has" way round.

Comment: I like this because it clearly indicates the many:many relationship, when the table names are singular.

Answer (score 2):

I've always gone with something like : `rel_user_roles` or `relUserRoles`. Which table goes first usually just depends on where it is in the data model.

Answer (score 2):

2 approaches:

1. where you will only ever have one relationship between the tables: join table could be RoleUser or Role_User.  Go alphabetic with your name order, Role 1st, then User, then you don't have to try to remember!
2. where you will have multiple relationships between the tables: *relationshipname* - e.g. you might have a list of regular roles for users, and you might have a list of potential, or past roles for users.  Same 2 tables, but different relationships.  Then you might have RoleUser_Current and RoleUser_Past.

Answer (score 1):

I have a convention which I find easy to see right away:

```
User
Role
User2Role
```

Answer (score 1):

`RoleUser` - I use alphabetic ordering (i.e. `Role` comes before `User`). That way when you're writing a query you won't have to try and remember which order you used to name the join table.

I also use singular as someone else mentioned - you don't have to try to remember!  Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

We've always used the names of the two tables followed by the word, 'Links'.
So in your example our table name would be 'UsersRolesLinks'.

Answer (score 0):

You could steal a page from Microsoft, and call it *UsersInRoles*.

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep things simple, but also be descriptive:

**user_role_join**

Answer (score 0):

Its good to name join table by using names of tables which it connects.
For example two tables "products" and "product_tags", and the joining table is called "product_product_tags".
The big advantage is that from this name you can immediatelly say which tables its joining together. When you have 50 and more tables in your DB its good to have it like this and you no longer need to think about joining tables purposes.

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, use table aliases and select the columns with same names apart with the AS selector.

e.g. `SELECT user.id AS user_id`