# Sql modifying relationships

Tags: sql, database, oracle

how do you change the  relationship between two tables to a many to many to many relationship in sql. Im using oracle for the DB.

thanks

Comment: You're going to need to provide much more information about what the content of these two tables are in order for someone to provide an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relationships among tables are almost always, **ONE-TO-MANY**, or **ONE-TO-ONE**. There is no **MANY-TWO-MANY** relationship between two tables. If you want a **MANY-TO-MANY** you will need to create intermediate relation to hold the relationship.

For example, if you want a **MANY-TO-MANY** relationship between table **A** and **B** you will need to create an intermediate table **C**:

```
create table a (a_id number primary key);
create table b (b_id number primary key);
-- c will hold many-to-many relationship between a and b
create table c (
    a_id number not null references a(a_id),
    b_id number not null references b(b_id),
    primary key(a_id, b_id)
);
```

Comment: +1 Table `c` can have many different names; Mapping table, a junction table, a relationship table, etc, etc.  There's even a question on SO just about its naming: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045034/whats-the-correct-name-for-a-association-table-many-to-many-relationship

Comment: "There is no MANY-TWO-MANY relationship between two tables" -- Can you explain what you mean please? As read, it appears to be a misstatement. I could post schema modelling a many-to-many relationship using one, two or three tables.

Comment: @onedaywhen: You can have MANY-TO-MANY relationships modeled with three or more tables. I don't think you can have one with one or two tables...