# SQL many-to-many tables relationship

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I have the following scenario: a student can enroll to more courses and on a cours can be enroll more different students.
What tables and how should I create for this to work properly?

Comment: You need an additional table that holds a course id and a student id. This way you can store all the relationships.

Comment: Thank you  Siderite Zackwehdex. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

It's called pivot table. All you need are the primary keys from the participating tables, in SQL in would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE student (sid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100));
CREATE TABLE course (cid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, desc TEXT);
CREATE TABLE enrollments (sid INTEGER, cid INTEGER, edate DATE, PRIMARY KEY (sid,cid), FOREIGEN KEY sid REFERENCES student(sid), FOREIGEN KEY cid REFERENCES course(cid));
```

As you see, you can even add more columns to the pivot table, like I did with the enrollment date.

Comment: That's not a pivot table. It has many names - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045034/whats-the-correct-name-for-a-association-table-many-to-many-relationship but never heard it called pivot.

Answer (score 0):

you should create another table (association table) that contains at least course_id and student_id .
these two columns are foreign keys that refer to tables course and student repectively