# MySQL many to many table convention

Tags: mysql, database-design

Assume that there is 2 tables `users` and `events`.

```
[ users ]
- id(PK)
- name
```

```
[ events ]
- id(PK)
- title
- description
```

Normally, pivot table(M:N) looks like this.

```
[ user_event ]
- id(PK)
- user_id(FK to users)
- event_id(FK to events)
```

Should I insert additional column to `user_event` m:n table?

```
[ user_event ]
- id(PK)
- user_id(FK to users)
- event_id(FK to events)
- is_leave
```

I have to check if user leave the event or not. So `is_leave` column is added to `user_event`.

I wonder that, is it a bad way?

Is there any convention here?

Thanks.

Comment: Linking tables often have columns that pertain to the two keys forming the link. For example, a table linking students and courses might have the grade that a particular student earned in a particular course.

Comment: This doesn't have an answer outside of a given information modelling method. What you "should" do is follow one & where stuck understanding or applying it ask a question about that while referencing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to add attribute columns to `user_event`, which I would call the intersection table*.

The rule should be if the attribute pertains to an individual user attending a particular event, then it's correct to put it in the intersection table.

In other words, it doesn't belong in the `users` table, because it doesn't apply to all events the user has attended. It doesn't belong in the `events` table, because it doesn't apply to all users of the given event.

---

* [There's no official terminology for this type of table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045034/whats-the-correct-name-for-an-association-table-a-many-to-many-relationship) I prefer "intersection table" but I've heard other terms.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Bill's "intersection" discussion...

- Get rid of the `id` it is useless and slows things down.
- Provide composite indexes in both directions.

Details and more tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table