# Changing LEFT JOIN to INSTR

Tags: mysql

I currently have the following query and it works because I have a column in t2 that contains the same ikey as t1:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        us_mkr.*,
        t1.ikey,
        t1.tag,
        t2.events
    FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN us_mkr ON (us_mkr.mkr_key = t1.ikey)
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON (t1.ikey = t2.ikey)
    WHERE t1.slug = '" . $_GET['title'] . "'
      AND us_mkr.county LIKE '%" . addslashes($county) . "%'";
```

However, I would like to change that column in t2 to store a string instead of a single key value. So I was thinking that all I could do is to change my JOIn to INSTR, like this:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT 
        us_mkr.*,
        t1.ikey,
        t1.tag,
        t2.events
    FROM t1 
    LEFT JOIN us_mkr ON (us_mkr.mkr_key = t1.ikey)
    LEFT JOIN t1 ON INSTR(t2.ikeys, t1.ikey) > 0
    WHERE t1.slug = '" . $_GET['title'] . "'
      AND us_mkr.county LIKE '%" . addslashes($county) . "%'";
```

But it doesn't seem to work so I wonder what am I missing.

Comment: Join operations can make use of indices when using single-valued fields. By choosing to use `INSTR`, you are likely to be worsening the performance of this query. What's the purpose of this change?

Comment: It sound like you should be using a intersection* table to record the many to many relationship. (* Or it can go by various other names https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045034/whats-the-correct-name-for-an-association-table-a-many-to-many-relationship/40623379#40623379)

Comment: @lemon I was just trying to reuse the content from t2 in several cases.

Comment: *change that column in t2 to store a string instead of a single key value* - No! don't do that! Unless of course the goal is to prevent efficient data access and decrease your performance and concurrency?

Comment: @stu Sorry, was that a suggestion or sarcasm?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I think I will explore adding the intersection table. I assume it'll contain t1.key = t2.id what would my query look like? Sounds like select with select? It's largely outside of my skill level.

Comment: @santa lol, well possibly maybe a little, just making the point that joining data via parsing strings is not how a relational database is designed to work - at least that's what I assumed you are saying you want to do - data you need to filter on, sort on, join on etc should be *atomic* otherwise the optimiser cannot seek on or benefit from the sorted nature if an index since it must examine each row every time to perform the *unsargable* operation.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/20860