# SQL naming convention for table that connects two tables?

Tags: sql, database

For example, you have tables `Users` and `Groups`; a user can be member of many groups, and a group has many users.

So how would you name the table that connects them?

Should it be `user_groups` or `group_members` ?

Personally, I think the latter is better.

Though it depends. If I want to know the groups of a user, I think the former is better. If I want to know the members of a certain group, I think the latter is better. However, I think it's not right to create both table since they are the same.

Comment: Define *better* - how is one naming *better* than the other? The important thing is: **you** need to come up with a naming convention, and then **stick to it** - what it is is really secondary ....

Comment: This is opinion based (so I'm voting to close).  My choice would be `UserGroups`.  It would have the names of the two related entities and be plural.

Comment: if is it used only for Users, then User_Groups, if is it used by other tables as well, then Group_Member. Aside from that, you need to keep in mind the tables list order, for instance, if you name it User_Groups, it'll be listed under User table, but if you named it Group_Member, it'll be listed in the top tables as tables are listing in ASC order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See first reply from [What should I name a table that maps two tables together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813321/what-should-i-name-a-table-that-maps-two-tables-together)

Your question can be considered as duplicate, because already exist one with a good answer there.

And my personal answer for your question, I prefer to use a prefix for all many-to-many tables, example : MapGroupUser, where "Map" is the prefix. So, all tables of this particular type will be different from the others

Answer (score 0):

I would like the table name to help me identify the tables from which it holds the data. Although group_members seems more logical, I would prefer users_groups as it clearly mentions the tables from which it holds data.