# Relationship between 3 tables using php

Tags: mysql

I need to create a relationship between 3 tables. I'm creating a members area, where I need to show the logged in user the courses he bought. The three tables are: `users`, `products`, `purchases`.

```
Users columns: id, name, email, password

Products columns: id, code, name, image, link

Purchases columns: id, code, email, value, date
```

I register the products through an interface and I get the purchases through a webhook. That is, the products that I register are the same codes that I receive from webhook

I need to know if the logged in user has purchased a course that is on my system and show it to him.

Comment: So what you have? `Shipping` / `Purchases` / `Course`...?

Comment: "The thee tables are: users, products, purchases." and then "user product shopping"  Is it user or users, product or products or purchases or shopping?

Comment: Under purchases have a list of products codes column and a user ID column, then check the purchases table with your logged in user's ID to get every product he's bought

Comment: You need to do some more learning about association tables and normalizing database tables.  Maybe take an SQL course on one of the many free sites that offer them.  Here's more information into specifically what you'd be looking for: http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Join Table Naming Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764483/sql-join-table-naming-convention)

Comment: @Asthmatic, Do you have a example of this?

Comment: @xQbert, you're right, I will correct this description

Answer (score 0):

So you're after a join between the tables on their unique keys and or indexes?

I'm assuming:

- ID is the primary key of each table; yet you're using unique indexes to relate them.
- Useres.email is a unique key.
- Product.code is a unique key.
- Purchases is a junction table showing what users(email) purchased what products(code)
- that you're after a query which shows you the productname, image and link as well as username and email of the logged in user.
- that a purchase implies a complete sale; and not just a shopping cart/wishlist.  Usually we see order, order detail, shipment, Invoice, payment etc when dealing with a ordering system.

.

```
SELECT PR.Name as ProductName, PR.Image, PR.Link, U.Name as userName U.Email 
FROM users U
INNER JOIN Purchases PU
 on PU.eMail = U.eMail
INNER JOIN Products PR
 on PR.Code = PU.Code
WHERE U.ID = {logged in user ID}
```