# Naming convention for sql join table to keep the name short

Tags: sql, naming-conventions, join, short, clarity

I have two tables:

```
provider_contact
provider_contact_role
```

Now i need a join table for those and what's coming to my mind first is:

Option 1: `provider_contact_provider_contact_role` but this is too long.

Option 2: `provider_contact_role` which ideally describes the purpose of the table, but that is exactly the same as second table's name :)

What is your suggestion ?

Comment: Give meaningful alias name for table

Comment: for example? Just want to know your opinion?

Comment: Give Option 2 it is meaningful ans also it is easy

Comment: As I mentioned option 2 is the exact same name as the 2nd table :) So I can't use that name

Comment: Take 1st alias as provider and 2nd alias as role

Comment: @SurenAznauryan Do you have only "provider_contact_role" table for roles or there are another Role tables? if it is the only one then I would recommend to rename it to "role" and then join name for two tables is clear.

Comment: @Mara I have other role tables as well

Answer (score 0):

You can always introduce an X to show that it's a JOIN table?

> provider_contact_X_role
>
> providercontactXrole
>
> contactXrole
>
> provider_X_role

[Naming Convention question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764483/sql-join-table-naming-convention)